# Artillery Load Testing: How to Capture, Store, Log 'requestId' from Received Response and Pass it in Another Request?

Tags: graphql, yaml, performance-testing, load-testing, artillery

When executing an Artillery test via the Windows command line, I observe the following response:

```
2023-12-12T13:52:17.968Z http:response "{\"data\":{\"postApiV1Memo\":{\"code\":200,\"data\":{\"requestId\":\"d2966c0e-c91f-46b7-964f-1635ee0bde8b-323032335134\"},\"message\":\"Success\"}}}"
  ok statusCode 200
```

In my YML configuration file, I've implemented code to capture and log specific fields, but unfortunately, I am unable to see the captured fields and logs (Also I am not able to Pass value from one request to another. e.g. in My case case I have to pass requestId to next request). Any insights into what might be missing or causing this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance for your assistance